# Xcode add remote repository (Bitbucket) failing

Tags: xcode, git, repository, bitbucket

I'm not able to add a new remote repository through Xcode on my older Macbook (circa 2006).

I keep getting the following error when entering the HTTPS location of my Bitbucket repository.

I get the following error: `Repository is offline` ... even though I'm able to connect with my newer Macbook Air

Has anyone else run into this issue, and/or what's causing this?